# What is my foreach mistake?

Tags: c#, sqlite, loops, foreach, listbox

I have a problem with my foreach loop. The prupose is to loop through items in a listbox and for every item there is, it should set the properties of the person equal to the properties of the person equal to a person object which i will insert into a list of persons.(The person has a item, with properties ect..). Problem: It inserts the first person with it's item into the list, but when it comes to the second person that it has to insert it changes the first person data to the same data as the second person data, and inserts the second person. So it always inserts the new person but changes all my old data that I have alredy inserted too be the same as the new person's.

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool bOK = false;

            if (UC.IsEmpty(txtFirstName) || UC.IsEmpty(txtLastName) || UC.IsEmpty(txtID) || lstItemsAdded.Text == null) //Maak seker van die listItemsAdded se content... hier sal n error wees... j kan nog n else maak dat hy spesefiek toets of daar items in die lstbox is
            {
                UC.MB("Customer Information Missing", "Please supply enough customer information");
            }
            else
            {
                bOK = true;
            }
            if (bOK) 
            {

                foreach (Item item in lstItemsAdded.Items)
                {
                        PersonItemObject.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
                        PersonItemObject.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
                        PersonItemObject.ID = txtID.Text;
                        PersonItemObject.Email = txtEmail.Text;
                        PersonItemObject.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

                        PersonItemObject.Item.ItemCode = item.ItemCode;
                        PersonItemObject.Item.ItemDescription = item.ItemDescription;
                        PersonItemObject.Item.ItemName = item.ItemName;
                        PersonItemObject.Item.ItemPrice = item.ItemPrice;
```

It is supposed to add all the items in the listBox to the list in the next statement, and for each item it should add the persons details too.

```
                        PersonItemsList.Add(PersonItemObject);
```

If I added more than 1 item to a person it changes my old data that i have added in the list to be the same as then new person data, and inserts a new person into the list too.

```
                    }
                DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is `PersonItemObject` defined ?

Comment: That's because you are adding the same `PersonItemObject` reference each time, you need to create a new `PersonItemObject` on each iteration of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every iteration you are updating properties of the same object, and then inserting it into the list. SO in the end list contains several referencies to the same object.

What you should do is craeting new object for each iteration:

```
foreach (Item item in lstItemsAdded.Items)
{
    PersonItem item = new PersonItem(); //just guessing the type here
    item.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    ...
    PersonItemsList.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new instance of your "*PersonItemObject*". Something like:

```
PersonItemObject = new PersonItemObjectClass()
```

as the first sentence of your loop, being *PersonItemObjectClass* the type of *PersonItemObject*. The problem here is, probably, you are using always the same instance and because of it the value is always changing.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to create a new instance of whatever type `PersonItemObject` is, inside the `foreach` loop.

What you're adding to the `PersonItemsList` is actually a *reference* to a single instance of your class. Every time you iterate the loop, you're updating the same instance, so you have a list of identical looking objects.

```
foreach (Item item in lstItemsAdded.Items)
{
    var PersonItemObject = new PersonItem();

    PersonItemObject.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    PersonItemObject.LastName = txtLastName.Text;

    ...

    PersonItemsList.Add(PersonItemObject);
}
```

You may want to read up on the differences between [value types and reference types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You have one PersonItemObject and you are changing it in every iteration.If you want to make a list of  PersonItemObjects then create a new instance on each iteration:

```
foreach (Item item in lstItemsAdded.Items)
{
    var PersonItemObject = new YourType();
    PersonItemObject.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    PersonItemObject.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanx alot, all your answers helped! It's working now

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're always changing the same `PersonItemObject`.  You should create a new version of this object each time and add it your list.

```
foreach (Item item in lstItemsAdded.Items)
{
    var newObject = new PersonItemObject();
    newObject.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
    newObject.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
    newObject.ID = txtID.Text;
    newObject.Email = txtEmail.Text;
    newObject.Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

    newObject.Item.ItemCode = item.ItemCode;
    newObject.Item.ItemDescription = item.ItemDescription;
    newObject.Item.ItemName = item.ItemName;
    newObject.Item.ItemPrice = item.ItemPrice;

    PersonItemsList.Add(newObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a new object each time you are setting the values to it. To create a new object the proper way would be like this:

```
foreach (Item item in lstItemsAdded.Items)
{
    var newObject = new PersonItemObject()
    {
        FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        LastName = txtLastName.Text;
        ID = txtID.Text;
        Email = txtEmail.Text;
        Age = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);

        Item.ItemCode = item.ItemCode;
        Item.ItemDescription = item.ItemDescription;
        Item.ItemName = item.ItemName;
        Item.ItemPrice = item.ItemPrice;
    }
    PersonItemsList.Add(newObject);
}
```